How to update query cache when we are using parameters in the main query call?
I am currently trying to implement Redux-Toolkit Query for the first time and am facing issue in delete item implementation. As mentioned by other people on this topic, I also face the issue of get item query being called again right after delete item is called. Here are my code snippets
getAllSchedules: builder.query({
  query: (params) => ({
    url: '/schedules/',
    params,
  }),
  transformResponse: (response) => ({
    schedules: response.results,
    pagination: {
      count: response.count,
      current_limit: response.limit,
      total_pages: response.total_pages,
      current_page: response.current_page,
    },
  }),
  providesTags: (result) =>
    Array.isArray(result?.schedules)
      ? [
        ...result.schedules.map(({ id }) => ({
          type: 'Schedule',
          id,
        })),
        'Schedule',
      ] : ['Schedule'],
    }),
getScheduleById: builder.query({
  query: (id) => `/schedules/${id}/`,
  providesTags: (result, error, id) => [{ type: 'Schedule', id }],
}),
deleteSchedule: builder.mutation({
  query: (id) => ({
    url: `/schedules/${id}/`,
    method: 'DELETE',
  }),
  invalidatesTags: (result, error, id) => [{ type: 'Schedule', id }],
}),

getAllSchedules and getScheduleById are used to get schedule data list and individual schedule data item respectively, while the last function is used to delete a single schedule item. I am doing the delete schedule operation inside a table listing, so want the data to be updated right after delete, but invalidating cache like this causes a getScheduleById call which does not exists in BE anymore and thus creating a 404 error.
I don't want this error to occur because it is shown to the user in the system because of default error handling in the site. But at the same time I can't do manual cache invalidation like this
onQueryStarted: async (id, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) => {
  try {
    const patchResult = dispatch(
      scheduleApiSlice.updateCachedData(
        'getAllSchedules',
        undefined,
        (draft) => {
          draft.schedules = draft.schedules.filter(
            (schedule) => schedule.id != id
          );
        }
      )
    );
    await queryFulfilled;
  } catch {
    patchResult.undo();
  }
},

because this requires me to pass all params to the getAllSchedules query same as before and as I am using pagination and searching for my listing, I have to supply all  the params related to it in this updateCache, which I can't do right now because I don't have access to it in handleDelete and I don't want to over complicate stuff by sharing the variables from listing to handleDelete and stuff. Is there a nice way to handle this?

Issue
Updating the cached data, i.e. scheduleApiSlice.updateCachedData, is not the same as invalidating query cache tags.
What you are doing with onQueryStarted is more akin to optimistic updates where you are deleting a schedule and optimistically removing it from the current cached data client-side. This is a mechanism you'd use in place of tag validation, e.g. not using cache tags and instead manually managing all the cached data yourself, and saving any re-fetches. But as you see though, you need to manage it all.
By including the id in the deleteSchedule endpoint's invalidatesTags value you are informing RTKQ to re-trigger all queries that provide that same tag, e.g. the getScheduleById query endpoint. Since you just deleted that document in the backend it doesn't make sense to trigger the frontend to re-fetch it.
Solution Suggestion

Remove id from the deleteSchedule endpoint's invalidatesTags array. Include only the "Schedule" tag value to trigger revalidating the getAllSchedules query endpoint.
Update to use both "Schedules" and "Schedule" tags.

getAllSchedules provides "Schedules" for the entire set and { type: "Schedule", id } for the individual schedule items.
getScheduleById provides just the individual { type: "Schedule", id } tag
deleteSchedule invalidates the "Schedules" tag



getAllSchedules: builder.query({
  query: (params) => ({
    url: '/schedules/',
    params,
  }),
  ...,
  providesTags: (result) =>
    Array.isArray(result?.schedules)
      ? [
        ...result.schedules.map(({ id }) => ({
          type: 'Schedule', // <-- only "schedule"
          id,
        })),
        'Schedules',        // <-- "schedules"
      ] : ['Schedules'],    // <-- "schedules"
}),
getScheduleById: builder.query({
  query: (id) => `/schedules/${id}/`,
  providesTags: (result, error, id) => [{ type: 'Schedule', id }],
}),
deleteSchedule: builder.mutation({
  query: (id) => ({
    url: `/schedules/${id}/`,
    method: 'DELETE',
  }),
  invalidatesTags: ['Schedules'], // <-- "schedules"
}),

If you were doing just about anything other than deleting a schedule, like just updating it, this is when you'd include the id value so you can trigger re-fetching just that specific schedule.

I actually tried this approach too. But it still calls the refetch query again, I don't know why. I thought that invalidating whole tag like this would work for my case, as I am doing the same thing in createItem request too. But don't know why this does not work for  delete. Am I doing something wrong, because my code looks just like yours when I try invalidating whole schedule list.

@TeaTech It's supposed to trigger the getAllSchedules endpoint, but not the getScheduleById endpoint for the schedule just deleted. Are you saying your getScheduleById endpoint is still triggered?

@DrewResse that's exactly what I thought too, but it does trigger the getScheduleById query, and I can see the initiator to be my handleDelete function in the networks tab.

@TeaTech Have you ensured (1) that your most recent changes are saved, and (2) you are running/serving the most recent version? I'll see if I can scrape up a small demo.

Yes, I can verify that my changes are saved and I am testing the recent version. I am currently running it on my local and can see the changes in Sources section of inspect. Also is this possible that my issue is occurring because I am transforming my response to separate out paging related details in getAllSchedules?

@TeaTech Ah, there's a very subtle issue in the tags you are providing and invalidating. You should use separate tags for the entire array of schedules, i.e "Schedules", and for individual schedules, i.e. "Schedule". getAllSchedules provides both "Schedules" for the set and { type: "Schedule", id } for each individual schedule item, getScheduleById provides the individual tag, and deleteSchedule invalidates the set with "Schedules". Does this make sense?

@TeaTech Here's a demo using the JSONPlaceholder API and "Posts" instead of "Schedules": https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lyzfgn

Thank you for the demo @DrewReese, I can see that the issue is not occurring in your code, I will try to regenerate the issue in your code and see if I am doing something wrong in the process instead.

Oh, I missed your above comment. Yes, my issue was that. I have updated my tag for listing from Schedule to Schedules and it started working. Thank you so much.

@TeaTech Welcome, happy to help. Sorry I missed the other tag issue first time around. Cheers and good luck!
